# liftweb sbt continuous integration tutorial

Tags: scala, continuous-integration, lift, sbt

We have a liftweb sbt project. We run 'container:start' in sbt for development but now we need a test deployment. Can we use Jenkins to do continuous integration? and How? I searched on web but found no tutorials about this topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using the Jenkins SBT plugin? See https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/sbt+plugin

Comment: That seems to be a dead project and it used sbt 0.7.x which are quite outdated. Thanks anyway.

Comment: In this blog (http://www.cakesolutions.net/teamblogs/2012/01/05/configuring-jenkins-plugin-for-sbt/) they are using that plugin to run SBT 0.11.2. I guess the command line interface has not changed that much